# How to minimize a command prompt window in batch file after launch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am running a batch file as a normal window, but want to minimize it after it has displayed certain information. I already know how to run a batch file so it is minimized at launch, but I need to to minimize after the information has been displayed, not before that information has been displayed.

Comment: A batch file has not way of communicating with the terminal window after it is launched, other than being able to close it using `exit`.

Comment: You can do that via my [SendMessage.exe](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7583) auxiliary program. For example: `SendMessage 274 61472` minimizes the window and is equivalent to **SendMessage WM_SYSCOMMAND SC_MINIMIZE**, although `SendMessage.exe` have _a lot_ of additional useful features...

Comment: I would need to use something that is already part of Windows without having to install something that might need to be licensed even if it is open source.